# How can I properly format the output generated by combining two Get-Azure cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, azure

I am taking the Name property from (Get-AzureVM), and the SubscriptionName property from (Get-AzureSubscription -Current) and throwing them into a text file. I am trying to get each VM on their own line but for some reason I'm ending up with {vm1,vm2,vm3,vm4...}. It doesn't wrap and does the '...' when there are more than 4 objects. How can I get this to show an output like this?

> vm1 Subscription1
>
> vm2 Subscription1
>
> vm3 Subscription1

This is my script so far:

```
cd C:\PowerShellThings
$machine = Get-AzureVM
$subscription = Get-AzureSubscription -Current
$props = @{
VMHostName  = $machine.Name
Subscription  = $subscription.SubscriptionName
    }
New-Object PSObject -Property $props | select VMHostName,Subscription | ft -HideTableHeaders -Wrap | Out-File VM-Subs2.txt -Append -NoClobber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate it with PS objects, try something along these lines.

```
$VMs = Get-AzureVM
$subscription = Get-AzureSubscription -Current
ForEach ($VM in $VMs) {
   "$($VM.Name): $($Subscription.SubscriptionName)" | out-file .\output.txt -append
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think of doing a for loop when writing this out. Nice, thanks!